# Google Sheets Script hideSheet() , Sheet not hidden

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to duplicate a hidden template, causing it to be revealed, but then have it be hidden again after the duplication.

The `hideSheet()` function is not working. Any ideas?

```
function googleQuiz(){

//Duplicate Sheet 
  var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('QuizFormTPlate'));
  ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
  sheet.hideSheet();
//Rename sheet
  var dSheet = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Copy of QuizFormTPlate'));
  var date = new Date();
  var tz = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var marksDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, tz, 'dd-MMM');
  var name = "G-Quiz ".concat(marksDate);
  dSheet.setName(name);
//Insert Cell 
  var cell = dSheet.getRange("C2");
  cell.setValue('Formative');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's "showSheet()" 
This works for me:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheetTemplate = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Template');
sheetTemplate.showSheet();
//do something...
sheetTemplate.hideSheet();
```

Since hideSheet() takes no effect if the sheet is already hidden:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidesheet

Showing the hidden sheet first should do the trick:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showsheet

Answer (score 0):

Here is alternative solution that will that copy the sheet and keep it hidden

```
function googleQuiz(){

//Duplicate Sheet 
  var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('QuizFormTPlate');
  var dSheet = sheet.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss.getId()))
  dSheet.showSheet()
//Rename sheet
  var date = new Date();
  var tz = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var marksDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, tz, 'dd-MMM');
  var name = "G-Quiz ".concat(marksDate);
  dSheet.setName(name);
//Insert Cell 
  var cell = dSheet.getRange("C2");
  cell.setValue('Formative');
}
```

Basically, instead of your using `duplicateActiveSheet()` function of a spreadsheet object. You can use [`copyTo()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet) function of a sheet object and provide it with the current spreadsheet. 
`sheet.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss.getId()))`.
And directly pass the new sheet object to `var dSheet` to make it visible and rename it.

Comment: Hi, this does allow the original sheet to remain hidden, But two issues if you can help. One the new sheet is not automatically displayed to the user.  Two, I have multiple Alternating Colours formatting which are not copied.  I do like that the new sheet apears as the new last tab.

Comment: Used `ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Copy of QuizFormTPlate'));` instead of `dSheet.showSheet()` to have the sheet appeare directly to the user. Formating is still an issue if you have any ideas?

Comment: Could you share a template sheet to try it out? The code at my end seems to be working as intended.

Comment: I think it was because I had multiple alternating colours.  I ended up sticking with the `duplicate` because it puts the next sheet in front of any previous duplicates rather than at the end of the workbook.  I also added `if(sheet.isSheetHidden==false){sheet.hideSheet}`

Answer (score 0):

It appears the issue is caused by using `setActiveSpreadSheet` on a hidden sheet, if you call `ss.getSheetByName('QuizFormTPlate').showSheet();` prior to the `ss.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss.getSheetByName('QuizFormTPlate'));` the call to `hideSheet()` will work fine afterwards. Posting this here so anyone else running into this problem can just add the `.showSheet()` instead of reworking their whole code.